# Update SQL column based on contains search from list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of varieties, each variety having codes like this

```
CLADIR(E611, E613, E614, E615, F120, F121, F122, F123, F188, F1D9, F1DA, F108)
VITIN(E620, F10A, F10E, F16B, F16C, F16D, F16E, F17D)
SOLO(E612, E617, E618, E619, F124, F125, F126, F127, F128, F1DB, F1DC)
JIMNA(E61E, F180)
```

I have data in existing database with different Varity names and codes(some codes are equal to one of these code from these varieties and some are not). I am working to update the Variety name based on the match for its code to any of these codes. If the code is not part of any of these codes, then I want to remove that row.

*Example data:*

```
Variety   Code
SNANA     F108
FLATO     E612
JAITI     X111
```

for the above data

1. SNANA will be updated as CLADIR as code F108 is one of the CLADIR's
   code from the list
2. FLATO will be updated as SOLO as code E612 is
   oneof the SOLO's code from the list
3. JAITI with code X111 row
   should be removed as X111 is not matching any of above varieties
   codes
   Is it possible to do this in straight sql? can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `case` expressions?

```
update t
    set variety = (case when code in ('E611', . . . ) then 'Cladir'
                        when code in ('E620', . . . ) then 'Vitin'
                        . . .
                   end);

-- The above sets the variety for non-matching codes to `NULL`, so delete those

delete from t
    where variety is null;
```

Comment: I think this works. I have to run this query on only few verities so I will include a where cluase with ```where variety in ('SNANA','FLATO','JAITI')```